# Cannot get/fetch keys from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array object where there are key value pairs. I am trying to get the keys  in that array using a loop but I am getting only `0`. What is  the problem with my code.

```
 var strj = '{"name":"John","age":"30","cars":
                                          [ {"type":"car", "year":"1998"}, 
                                            {"type":"van", "year":"1995"}]}';
    var myobj = JSON.parse(strj)

var care = myobj.cars.filter(c => c.type=='car');
```

Value of care

```
0:{type: "car", year: "1998"}
length:1
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Loop

```
for (var key in care){
    if(care.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an array, you'll need to do `care[0]` otherwise the key _will be_ the index, which is why the output is `0`

Comment: you did a filter and asked for the function to return only the type `car` which you only have one of. Value of care is as expected. Since `care` is a regular array, it's keys are indeed, 0,1,2,3,4..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`care` is a array type so you cannot do `for (var key in care)`. You need to do `for (var key in care[0])`. This is because `for (var key in care)` will look for the key value in `care` and since it is a array it will always take `0` as a value in `key`(as you have only one object in array and its index is 0). That is why you got `0` in `console.log`.

```js
var care =[{type: "car", year: "1998"}];
for (var key in care[0]){
    if(care[0].hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log(key)
    }
}
```

Comment: Or if they do only want one object and not an array `myobj.cars.find(c => c.type=='car')` would be better

Answer (score 1):

```
care.forEach( ( singleCar ) => {

    for ( var key in singleCar ){
        console.log(key);

        if( care.hasOwnProperty( key ) ){
            console.log(key);

        }
    }

})
```

`forEach` will give you all the objects one by one. so you can check them.

Answer (score 1):

As others have solved the issue, might i make a suggestion - Object.keys () gives an array of the keys for a given object. Since you are getting your filtered object and simply want its keys - the following will achieve that. Note that this is only using the code after you have filtered the original and have gained the "care" object.

As an aside, note that object.values() will give you an array of the values in a given object and object.entries() will give you arrays of the key / value pairing.

```js
var care = {type: "car", year: "1998"};
var keys = Object.keys(care)
console.log(keys) // gives ["type","year"]
```

Answer (score 1):

filter() method returns a Array of matches.

```
var care = myobj.cars.filter(c => c.type=='car'); // So, this returns an array.

care.forEach(element => {
    console.log(Object.keys(element)); //Prints keys of each element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually there is no problem in your code at all. But you just misunderstood the use of javascript filter. Javascript `filter()` creates new array that's why you are getting `0` as `key`. If you want to get only one matching element then `find()` is what you should use.

```
var strj = '{"name":"John","age":"30","cars":[{"type":"car", "year":"1998"},{"type":"van", "year":"1995"}]}';
var myobj = JSON.parse(strj)
var care = myobj.cars.filter(c => c.type == 'car'); // returns array
var care = myobj.cars.find(c => c.type == 'car'); // returns first matching object
var care = myobj.cars.findIndex(c => c.type == 'car'); // returns first matching index
```

1. Javascript `filter()` method => [Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
2. Javascript `find()` => [Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
3. Javascript `findIndex()` method => [Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)